# m2epro - Amazon Variations Missing Attribute

Tags: amazon

Our variation listings on Amazon are failing due to a missing attribute "size".

size_name is a required attribute for the apparel category we are submitting to. Our variations use an attribute called "Waist" in the Admin & Default store view to specify a size. The m2epro Amazon listing uses the store view "Amazon" and the "Waist" attribute label for that store view is "Size".

When we attempt to list a configurable "Waist" product on Amazon it kicks back saying a size must be specified. Size is referring to the required specific "size_name". There is no "Size Name" specific available in our ASIN Template. "SizeName" is not in the database table "m2epro_amazon_dictionary_specific" either.

Would that normally be added by the label of the variation attribute "Waist"? IE, should my attribute be labeled "Size", "Size_Name", or "SizeName"? If so, does it have to be the admin value label? I've experiments with various labels for the associated store view without success.

We have already listed all of our items to ebay using the waist attribute so changing the admin value of "Waist" would require stopping every listing.

Here is an image showing some of the settings we have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qo33.jpg

Post on m2epro that did not make sense to me as we cannot specify a missing specific: http://support.m2epro.com/knowledgebase/articles/35919-i-got-listing-is-missing-required-item-specific

Anyone have any insight?